# Colorful text with kivy?

Tags: kivy

I am writing something that would look like an IDE, however when typing something in TextInput I understand that everything is in a single color. Is it possible to be colorful? Or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here in the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.codeinput.html#kivy.uix.codeinput.CodeInput) there is `CodeInput` that is used for displaying highlighted code. I think this is what your looking for.